# uml-designer: 'Create Representation Wizard' empty

Tags: wizard, uml-designer

I'm trying out the uml-designer plugin and a tutorial ask me to select 'UML Structural Modeling' -> 'Class diagram' in the 'Create Representation Wizard'.
But when I open the wizard it's empty.
Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. The solution I found: Right click on your project in the "model explorer" and click on "Migrate to UML Designer 4.0" . Than, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not up-to-date, you should select the Design viewpoint and under it you will find the Class Diagram:
[image: Create a new Class diagram]

I created an issue to update the documentation : https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/962

Comment: The problem is that the window is fully empty. I have the text field with "Type filter text" and below that is an empty box. I don't have those 'Capture', 'Design' and 'Extend' subdivision.

Answer (score 0):

First right click on project and select "Select viewpoints" --> mark all 5 views. Then resume to "Create Representation" and you will see all options

Answer (score 0):

Mouse right click on your project in **Model Explorer** then *New* -> *UML Model*. Name it as you wish and click finish.

Double click on your just created .uml, in **NewModel** window choose which type of UML  you are going to have and then new window and **palette** will appear respectively.

If Palette is not visible, you can view it from *Window* -> *Show View* -> *Other* -> *General* -> *Palette*.